# Castle Windsor inject types dynamically based on attributes or config file

Tags: castle-windsor

I have an idea to design something like this. My class can accept a sequence of exception handlers that are registered when an instance of the class is created.

```
class Foo {
    public Foo (IEnumerable<UnhandledExceptionEventHandler> handlers) {
        foreach(var handler in handlers) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += handler;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to do something like this. I want to have Castle Windsor inject the handlers for me either based on attributes applied to the class

```
[LogExceptions(typeof(SomeExceptionHandler), typeof(AnotherExceptionHandler))]
class Foo { // code }
```

or specified in a config file. So in the former example, when Castle Windsor wants to resolve an instance of `Foo`, it would look at the `LogExceptions` attribute and see that it needs to construct `Foo` via

```
new Foo(new[] { new SomeExceptionHandler(), new AnotherExceptionHandler() });
```

What are the concepts in Castle Windsor that I want to look at that will enable me to solve this problem?

If my design is retarded, please say so but offer constructive ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best extension point for stuff like that is [ComponentModel construction contributors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx). You will need to discover what handlers apply to your component, and then construct an array of service override dependencies for them.